# extract number from cell in openoffice calc

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-calc, libreoffice

I have a column in open office like this:

abc-23

abc-32

abc-1

Now, I need to get only the sum of the numbers 23, 32 and 1 using a formula and regular expressions in calc.
How do I do that?

I tried

```
=SUMIF(F7:F16,"([:digit:].)$")
```

But somehow this does not work.

Comment: Is the problem recurring enough to make writing a macro worth it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting with LibreOffice 6.4, you can use the newly added [REGEX function](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.2/en-US/text/scalc/01/func_regex.html) to generically extract all numbers from a cell / text using a regular expression:

```
=REGEX(A1;"[^[:digit:]]";"";"g")
```

**Replace `A1`** with the cell-reference you want to extract numbers from.

### Explanation of `REGEX` function arguments:

Arguments are separated by a semicolon `;`

1. `A1`: Value to extract numbers from. Can be a cell-reference (like `A1`) or a quoted text value (like `"123abc"`). The following regular expression will be applied to this cell / text.
2. `"[^[:digit:]]"`: Match every character which is not a decimal digit. See also [list of regular expressions in LibreOffice](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.2/en-US/text/shared/01/02100001.html?&DbPAR=WRITER&System=MAC)

   - The outer square brackets `[]` encapsulate the list of characters to search for
   - `^` adds a **NOT**, meaning that every character *not* included in the search list is matched
   - `[:digit:]` represents any decimal digit
3. `""`: replace matching characters (every non-digit) with nothing = remove them
4. `"g"`: replace all matches (don't stop after the first non-digit character)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Libre-Office only supports regex in find/replace and in search.
If this is a once-only deal, I would copy column A to column to B, then use [data] [text to columns] in B and use the - as a separator, leaving you with all the text in column B and the numbers in column C.

Alternatively, you could use =Right(A1,find("-",A1,1)+1) in column B, then sum Column C.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is not exactly what do you want, but maybe it can help you or others.

It is all about `substring` (in `Calc` called `[MID][1]` function):

**First:** Choose your cell (for example with "`abc-23`" content).

**Secondly:** Enter the start length ("`british`" --> `start length 4 = tish`).

**After that:** To print all remaining text, you can use the `[LEN][2]` function (known as length) with your cell ("`abc-23`") in parameter.
Code now looks like this:

```
D15="abc-23"
=MID(D15; 5; LEN(D15))
```

And the output is: `23`

When you edit numbers (in this example 23), no problem. However, if you change **anything before** (text "`abc-`"), the algorithm collapses because the start length is defined to "5".

Answer (score 1):

Paste the string in a cell, open search and replace dialog (ctrl + f) extended search option mark regular expression search for ([\s,0-9])([^0-9\s])+ and replace it with $1

adjust regex to your needs

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure out how to do this in OpenOffice/LibreOffice directly. After frustrations in searching online and trying various formulas, I realised my sheet was a simple CSV format, so I opened it up in vim and used vim's built-in sed-like feature to find/replace the text in vim command mode:

```
:%s/abc-//g
```

This only worked for me because there were no other columns with this matching text.  If there are other columns with the same text, then the solution would be a bit more complex.

If your sheet is not a CSV, you could copy the column out to a text file and use vim to find/replace, and then paste the data back into the spreadsheet.  For me, this was a lot less frustrating than trying to figure this out in LibreOffice...

Comment: Well, you did not read Felix' answer, did you? It is the same algorithm in LO. You never learn something new if you don't try. ;-)

Comment: @busybee I'll try it out when I get time.  Right now, expat taxes are coming due, on top of work and other things, so getting the job done is more of a priority than fiddling.

Answer (score -4):

I won't bother with a solution without knowing if there really is interest, but, you could write a macro to do this. Extract all the numbers and then implement the sum by checking for contained numbers in the text.